# Can I plug two Macs (a mini and a 12") into the same LG Ultrafine using Thunderbolt?

Tags: thunderbolt

I'm just wondering what happens - can I switch between the two displays? Will it just stay with the first mac connected, but charge the second mac?

Will the whole thing explode in a glorious shower of sparks, leaving me sobbing?

I've had a good google around, could not find the answer. I'm guessing it's just obvious to everybody except me!